# Magento #1005 - Can't create table '...' (errno: 121) ERROR

Tags: mysql, magento

I had an issue with my `magento` website, now the the site is down. but I have my db backup. but when I import the db , it gives me this error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table '' (errno: 121);
```

for this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `admin_rule` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ADMIN_RULE_ROLE_ID_ADMIN_ROLE_ROLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `admin_role` (`role_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This error is coming for all the alter commands. this is one example I'm showing u
Here is the table structure of admin_rule

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_rule` (
`rule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rule ID',
`role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Role ID',
`resource_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Resource ID',
  `privileges` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Privileges',
  `assert_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Assert ID',
  `role_type` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Role Type',
  `permission` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Permission',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rule_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ADMIN_RULE_RESOURCE_ID_ROLE_ID` (`resource_id`,`role_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ADMIN_RULE_ROLE_ID_RESOURCE_ID` (`role_id`,`resource_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Rule Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: It might be that you are referencing a table which is not yet created.

Comment: table is present Mihai

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table `admin_role`  exists and has a column named `role_id` that is primary key on that table and has the same exact type as `role_id` in `admin_rule`

I created it in sqlfiddle and it works:

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eca59)</kbd>

Comment: I have already installed the table and checked the role_id with the primary key too.. There are around 20-25 ALTER queries at the end of db backup files which are not executing at all showing up with the same error

Comment: Try doing: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` before executing the script. Make sure to do:  `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;` after.

Comment: i didnt get u Filipe.. Can u please elaborate ur answer so that i can try with ur solution..

Comment: That's a command to disable foreign key checks. My suspicion is your foreign key validations are the problem. If you are doing a mass create/alter tables, you can do that command before executing the script, so you can create/alter your tables without validations. And after executing it, put it back to 1. [Link to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)

Comment: Then i'm out of ideas on how to help. Can you put your whole script in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to take a closer look?